# Overloading operator ->

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Here is my code example:

```
class X
{
public:
        void f() {}
};

class Y : public X
{
public:
        X& operator->() { return *this; }
        void f() {}
};

int main()
{
        Y t;
        t.operator->().f(); // OK
        t->f(); // error C2819: type 'X' does not have an overloaded member 'operator ->'
                // error C2232: '->Y::f' : left operand has 'class' type, use '.'
}
```

Why the compiler is trying to "move the responsibility" for operator-> from Y to X? When I implement X::op-> then I cannot return X there - compile error says "infinite recursion" while returning some Z from X::op-> again says that Z doesn't have operator->, thus going higher and higher in hierarchy.

Can anyone explain this interesting behavior? :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that `operator ->` is supposed to return a *pointer*, not a *reference*.  The idea is that `operator ->` should return a pointer to the real object that should have the pointer applied to it.  For example, for a class with an overloaded `operator ->`, the code

```
myClass->myValue;
```

translates into

```
(myClass.operator-> ())->myValue;
```

The problem with your code is that `operator ->` returns a reference, so writing

```
myClass.operator->().f();
```

is perfectly legal because you're explicitly invoking the operator, but writing

```
myClass->f();
```

is illegal, because the compiler is trying to expand it to

```
myClass.operator->()->f();
```

and the return type of `operator->` isn't a pointer.

To fix this, change your code so that you return a pointer in `operator ->`.  If you want to overload an operator to return a reference, overload `operator *`; pointer dereferences should indeed produce references.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's suppose to return a pointer, just that whatever it returns needs to support `operator->`.

Comment: @GMan- Good point.  I was going for simplicity here, but you're correct.  There are some really fun tricks you can pull off with smart pointers that rely on this technique.

Comment: @GMan: Since such types are collectively called *smart pointers*, I don't think templatetypedef is wrong to use the term *pointer*, he's just using it in a general sense.

Comment: Although not completely correct "The problem is that operator -> is supposed to return a pointer, not a reference." answered my question in one sentence.

Answer (score 20):

Because that's how overloaded `->` works in C++.

When you use overloaded `->`, expression `a->b` is translated into `a.operator->()->b`. This means that your overloaded operator `->` must return something that will itself support another application of operator `->`. For this reason a single invocation of overloaded `->` might turn into a long chain of invocations of overloaded `->`s until it eventually reaches an application of built-in `->`, which ends the chain.

In your case you need to return `X*` from your overloaded `->`, not `X&`.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is wrong, should be:

**T->T2**
​

```
T2* T::operator ->();​
```

Look at wikipedia's article: [Operators in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

If you want to overload, you must use the right syntax for the overloaded operator

Answer (score 1):

You probably want:

```
class Y : public X
{
public:
        X* operator->() { return this; }
        void f() {}
};
```