# Is operator-> "chained" for pointers?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, method-chaining

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overloading operator ->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896238/overloading-operator)

Hi,

I've seen that `operator->()` is chained (re-applied) after it is evaluated, for example:

```
struct Bar
{
  Bar() : m_str("Hello world!") {}
  const string* operator->() const { return &m_str; }
  string m_str;
};

struct Foo
{
  const Bar& operator->() const { return m_bar; }
  Bar m_bar;
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  cout << f->c_str() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

works pretty fine, which requires three `operator->()` to be evaluated - `Foo::operator->()`, `Bar::operator->()` and regular pointer resolution.

But it wont work with pointers in the middle - if `Foo::operator->()` returns pointer to Bar instead of reference, it wont compile. Same happens with `auto_ptr<auto_ptr<string>>`  for example.

Is it specific to non-overloaded `operator->()` so it is only applied once and does not cause chaining?
Is it possible to make code below works without using `(*ptr2)-> ...`?

```
int main()
{
  string s = "Hello world";
  auto_ptr<string> ptr1(&s);
  auto_ptr<auto_ptr<string> > ptr2(&ptr1);
  cout << ptr1->c_str() << endl; // fine
  cout << ptr2->c_str() << endl; // breaks compilation
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [Overloading operator ->](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896238/overloading-operator) [AndreyT's answer explains the behavior of `operator->` and how the "chaining" occurs.]

Comment: @James I'd favor keeping this open since the wording of the question is different. It may help other people find that answer.

Comment: @Judge:  A closed question isn't automatically deleted, and a well-asked question like this one won't be deleted; the question will still exist and be searchable.

Comment: Thanks! And then it does not seems to be possible to override operator-> for pointer, so nothing can be done with second question. Right?

Comment: It should be note that using `auto_ptr` this way will cause all kinds of horrible things to happen when the variables are destroyed at the end of the function.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

C++98 standard §13.5.6/1 "Class member access":

> An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T::operator->` exists and if the operator is selected at the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3).

What this means in practice is that when `x` is a pointer, you don’t get chaining; you then just get the built-in `operator->` (i.e. `x->m` with `x` a pointer translates to `(*x).m`).

But when `x` is an object of class type `T`, then you can get the chaining effect. Because then the interpretation as `(x.operator->())->m` can be that `(x.operator->())` itself is an object of some class, say class `U`. Whence the second `->` can be resolved as `U::operator->`, and so on, if the result of that again is a class type object…

Like, in your case, `Foo::operator->` produces (a reference to) an object of class `Bar`, which does define an `operator->`.

But when `operator->` returns a pointer, as e.g. `std::auto_ptr<T>::operator->` does, then it's just the built-in `operator->` that's used.

In passing, the chaining *can* be used to practically prevent someone from using `delete` inappropriately. `std::auto_ptr` does not do that. And I’ve never seen it done.

But there was once a long discussion thread over in [comp.lang.c++.moderated] about how to prevent inadvertent `delete` of the raw pointer managed by a smart pointer, and this was one possibility that was discussed.

Cheers & hth.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your first example works is because you returned a reference instead of a pointer. That operator would normally be invalid except in the case that it is overloaded. Therefore, the compiler must execute the overloaded functions down the chain. However, in the case of `auto_ptr` you actually are returned a real pointer and the default `operator ->` is invoked for regular pointers.

Please see the [Overloading operator ->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896238/overloading-operator) question for more details.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was looking for approach to simplify code for iterating vector<shared_ptr<X> > and similar stuff. Seems that the only option is to specialize vector's (any container) iterator for shared_ptr (some other smart ptrs), which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible for it to work. If you could overload `operator ->` for `string *` you could make it work. But `operator ->` already has a definition for all pointer types. So, just like you can't overload `+` for primitive numeric types, you can't overload `operator ->` for any pointer type.

And even if you could, how could the compiler know when the recursion should end?