# Implementing operator-> for an iterator that does not return the true underlying type

Tags: c++, iterator

Suppose I want to implement the iterator for a class that represents an array of 2D points.
The iterator should make it look like that the class stores an array of pairs of doubles, but the class really uses 2 separate arrays (one for X coordinates and one for Y coordinates). I am wondering how I should implement the `operator->()` of the iterator. I certainly cannot take the address of the returned value from `operator*` because it's a temporary value. Should I allocate a `pair<double&, double&>` on the heap every time the `operator->()` is called? Is there a good way to do this?

```cpp
struct PointArray {
    std::vector<double> m_x;
    std::vector<double> m_y;

    // Define a custom iterator class for ControlPointArray
    class iterator {
    public:
        using value_type = std::pair<double&, double&> const;
        using reference = value_type;
        using pointer = value_type*;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

        iterator() = default;
        iterator(const typename std::vector<double>::iterator& x_it, const typename std::vector<double>::iterator& y_it)
            : m_x_it(x_it), m_y_it(y_it) {}

        reference operator*() const { return { *m_x_it, *m_y_it }; }
        pointer operator->() const {
            // how to implement this method ??
        }

        iterator& operator++() { ++m_x_it; ++m_y_it; return *this; }
        iterator operator++(int) { auto copy = *this; ++(*this); return copy; }
        iterator& operator--() { --m_x_it; --m_y_it; return *this; }
        iterator operator--(int) { auto copy = *this; --(*this); return copy; }
        iterator& operator+=(difference_type n) { m_x_it += n; m_y_it += n; return *this; }
        iterator operator+(difference_type n) const { auto copy = *this; copy += n; return copy; }
        iterator& operator-=(difference_type n) { return (*this) += -n; }
        iterator operator-(difference_type n) const { auto copy = *this; copy -= n; return copy; }
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const { return m_x_it - other.m_x_it; }
        reference operator[](difference_type n) const { return *(*this + n); }
        bool operator==(const iterator& other) const { return m_x_it == other.m_x_it; }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& other) const { return !(*this == other); }
        bool operator<(const iterator& other) const { return m_x_it < other.m_x_it; }
        bool operator<=(const iterator& other) const { return m_x_it <= other.m_x_it; }
        bool operator>(const iterator& other) const { return m_x_it > other.m_x_it; }
        bool operator>=(const iterator& other) const { return m_x_it >= other.m_x_it; }

    private:
        typename std::vector<double>::iterator m_x_it;
        typename std::vector<double>::iterator m_y_it;
    };

    // Define begin() and end() functions to return iterators
    iterator begin() { return { m_x.begin(), m_y.begin() }; }
    iterator end() { return { m_x.end(), m_y.end() }; }

// the rest of the PointArray class...
};
```

Comment: Overloading or implementing a custom `operator->()` is a tricky thing. Note from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4928709/10871073) that your own `operator*` isn't called but (rather) the **in-built** dereferencing is used. Not sure if that's your problem, though ... just sayin'.

Comment: If you go the `pair<double&, double&>` route, there's no reason to do heap allocation. You could simply return it by value

Comment: @MooingDuck I thought that `operator->()` **must** return a pointer, or at least a pseudo-pointer type. See also the last part of [this canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/10871073).

Comment: @AdrianMole you're right, I had to pause and think a little harder. I worked out the details, but have now posted them as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a pseudo-pointer that itself contains the values.

```
struct pseudo_pointer {
   value pair_of_data;
   pointer operator->() const {return &pair_of_data;}
};

pseudo_pointer operator->() const {
    return pseudo_pointer{{ *m_x_it, *m_y_it }};
}
```

This is pseudo-code off the top of my head and probably needs further tweaks to compile

Comment: If I recall, I learned this because I was trying to figure out how `std::vector<bool>::iterator::operator->()` was implemented, and then had to read it like 4 times to figure out what was going on there